Docker container of Nest project unable to connect AWS S3 bucket
Docker container of Nest project unable to connect AWS S3 bucket. From local able to connect s3 bucket. But after building the Docker image and when entering the image, I am unable to connect s3 bucket.
Only error that I am getting in Logs: Region is Missing
I am assuming there must be a settings for docker to communicate with s3 bucket, or need to provide the bucket link, or somewhere need to provide the region in dockerfile.
